# SVG opacity in unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, svg

I have an SVG Image component for which I am trying to set its color setting to one with non complete opacity. 
When I do so, each element is handled independently it seems, resulting in visible overlap.

[image]

From my understanding of the SVG format, it depends on the use of `fill-opacity` or `opacity`, however it didn't change anything in unity after I tried the 2 arguments in my svg source file.
I also tried to group my element in my svg files but it didn't work either. 
The problem seems to come from the way the SVG Image component's colors setting works.
Any tips ?

Answer (score 0):

Put your svg elements into a **Canvas**, with `CanvasGroup` component, then change the **alpha** of the `CanvasGroup`.

Comment: I added a canvas group component on my element and changed its alpha and it acted the same